# Django Upgrade From 1.8.8 to 1.11.13 Issue

Tags: django

I am getting the following error. I have added the sites framework, allowed the domain and updated the middleware and context processors but cant fathom this error. Any help would be appreciated as this is live at the minute.

```
manager@web-server:~/Websites/shen$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>    
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management    /__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_thumbnails/models.py", line 6, in <module>
from easy_thumbnails import utils, signal_handlers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_thumbnails/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
from easy_thumbnails.conf import settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_thumbnails/conf.py", line 334, in <module>
settings = Settings()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_thumbnails/conf.py", line 21, in __init__
super(AppSettings, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: What is the version of your easy_thumbnails package?

Comment: Make sure you use a version of `easy_thumbnails` that's compatible with Django 1.11